# Can't connect MongoDB Atlas from Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

So everything is working on my localhost, but when I try to open it on heroku I get

"could not connect to mongodb MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-sjxl2.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to cluster0-shard-00-01-sjxl2.mongodb.net:27017 closed" in Heroku logs

I'm pretty new to node js so probably something is wrong with connection
[image: I have MOngodb uri setup]

so I have my mongodb_uri setup,then

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
MongoClient.connect((process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://admin:root@cluster0-sjxl2.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'), { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(connect => console.log('connected to mongodb..'))
    .catch(e => console.log('could not connect to mongodb', e))
```

It seems simple and like it should work just that, but something is wrong.

Comment: 1. Have you [whitelisted](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) your IP?
2. Do you actually have `urlOfYourMongoDatabase` in front of your connection string?

Comment: Okay, so where can I find that url ? And Yes I have my ip whitelisted

Comment: Have you whitelisted your IP as all IPs? `0.0.0.0/0` as [heroku doesn't have a static outbound IP](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku). And make sure your username and password is set to something else, because your credentials are now exposed to the public.